# import times from txt: "File ended while scanning use of \pgfplotslibdateplot@map@time."

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, dateplot

i have a problem using a time axis and imported data from a txt file.

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\usepgfplotslibrary{dateplot, statistics}

\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\usepackage{filecontents}


\begin{filecontents*}{data2.txt}
09:04:08    887.2999878
09:04:09    887.2999878
09:04:10    887.4000244
09:04:11    887.4000244
09:04:12    887.4000244
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[  
        date coordinates in = x,
        xticklabel          = \hour:\minute]
        \addplot [draw=none] table[col sep = space] {data2.txt};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Whenever i run this code, i get the error:
File ended while scanning use of \pgfplotslibdateplot@map@time.

I have no idea what went wrong, since i think i ended all commands properly.

Thanks for any help in advance

*edited some unnecessary code out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that the library supports time without date. This here works for me:

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\usepgfplotslibrary{dateplot, statistics}

\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

%\usepackage{filecontents} %not needed in new latex
\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{data2.txt} %overwrite needs new latex
2020-01-27 09:04:08,    887.2999878
2020-01-27 09:04:09,    887.2999878
2020-01-27 09:04:10,    887.4000244
2020-01-27 09:04:11,    887.4000244
2020-01-27 09:04:12,    887.4000244
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
        date coordinates in = x,
        xticklabel          = \hour:\minute
        ]
        \addplot [draw=none] table[col sep = comma] {data2.txt};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for helping me with my problem. It works now.